# Computed.alias not updating bind-attr

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I recently started using Ember.js. In my small application I currently have problems regarding `Ember.computed.alias`, because an `{{#if}}`-section is updated properly, but the `bind-attr` helper in the same template is not updated accordingly.

The application controller and the action influencing the value look as follows:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isEditing: false,
    actions: {
        toggleEdit: function() {
            var a = this.get('isEditing');
            this.set('isEditing', !a);
        }
    }
});
```

The controller taking care of the template causing problems:

```
App.CategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
     needs: ['application'],
     isEditing: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.application.isEditing'),
     general: function() { // example depending on the alias
        var result = this.filterBy('type', 1);
        if (!this.get('isEditing')) {
            result = result.filterBy('isHidden', false);
         }
         return result;
     }.property('@each.type', '@each.isHidden', 'isEditing'),
     // ......
```

The related template:

```
<ul id="categories">
    {{#if isEditing}}YES!{{else}}NO!{{/if}}
    {{#each general}}
        <li {{bind-attr class=":general isEditing:editing"}}>
            {{name}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

When the action toggleEdit is triggered, the `{{#if}}` section is updated and swaps between `YES!` and `NO!`, but the `editing` class is not applied to the list element. I tried encapsulated the alias into another property of the controller depending on the alias, but without success.

I assume it's a beginners mistake, but I can't figure out what I am overlooking.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isEditing` is no longer in scope, use `controller.isEditing`, sorry phone response

Here's an example that would keep it in scope, but I'm fully qualifying it just to show you.

```
{{#each item in general}}
    <li {{bind-attr class=":general controller.isEditing:editing"}}>
        {{item.name}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```